# I am using the Files.move function to move a file, but it does not inherit the parent folder permissions

Tags: java, file, permissions, system

I am trying to move files from 1 directory to another. The problem is that when the files are in their new directory, they keep their previous permissions, and not the new ones that have been set for that folder.

I am trying this in my Java 8 application for on a local machine/client. I have tried looking for an answer but all I found were Linux and C# examples.

I have tried changing the ACL permission change settings in the OS/Server but Windows already handles the ACL permission swapping properly, it's just the Java code that ignores this.

I really want to use the move method, and not the copy+delete methods.

This is the only line of code I am using:

`Files.move(pdfFile.toPath(), Paths.get(newFileWithoutExtension + ".pdf"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

I expect that the file I am moving to a new directory will inherit the ACL permissions that have been set for that directory.

Currently moved files keep their own ACL permissions from where they were created, which is not as expected.

Edit 1: Changed permissions to ACL permissions.

Comment: Which permissions do you mean? The DOS permissions (could be set e.g. with `attrib`) or the ACL permission (could be set e.g. with `icacls`)?

Comment: @SubOptimal I mean the ACL permissions, sorry I did not know they were called that. I will edit my original question to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation

> Currently moved files keep their own ACL permissions from where they were created, which is not as expected.

Seems to be the expected behavior. Following the Microsoft support article [How permissions are handled when you copy and move files and folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/310316/how-permissions-are-handled-when-you-copy-and-move-files-and-folders).

> By default, an object inherits permissions from its parent object, either at the time of creation or when it is copied or moved to its parent folder. The only exception to this rule occurs when you **move an object to a different folder** on the same volume. In this case, **the original permissions are retained**.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: Do you want to make it portable across Unix/Windows?
 
Because each OS has specific file attributes.

For the Portable solution (attributes common to most of the OSs):

1. Get the **BasicFileAttributes** from the destination folder you are moving to. ex:

   > BasicFileAttributes basicAttr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
2. Set the attributes to each moved file

For the OS specific solution, instead of the BasicFileAttributes, you can use:

- **DosFileAttributes** for Windows:

  > DosFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, DosFileAttributes.class);
  >   
  > **//To get attribute values**
  >
  >   boolean isArchive = attrs.isArchive()
  >   boolean isHidden = attrs.isHidden()
  >   boolean isReadOnly = attrs.isReadOnly()
  >   boolean isSystem = attrs.isSystem()
  >   
  > **//To set attributes in the new file**
  >   Files.setAttribute(newFile, "dos:archive", isArchive);
  >   Files.setAttribute(newFile, "dos:hidden", isHidden);
  >   Files.setAttribute(newFile, "dos:readonly", isReadOnly);
  >   Files.setAttribute(newFile, "dos:system", isSystem);

- **PosixFileAttributes** for Unix

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but where do I get the permissions from using this? I checked the JDocs but I did not find any methods that could do this? Most of the methods only return a boolean.

Comment: BasicFileAttributes basAtr = Files.readAttributes(file,BasicFileAttributes.class);

Comment: When I do this I do get an object of this type, but then what can I use it for? I do not see a method I can call to see which permissions are set for this file, or a way to copy all attributes from one file to the other?

Sorry for forgetting about the OS question, it'll be Windows only.

Comment: Ah yes but those I did see, but does this cover which user has which permissions? It doesn't seem like it to me? Maybe I mis-communicated which kind of permissions I meant, but we have different permissions for different users and groups.

Comment: Permissions per groups and users in Windows? That doesn't exist.